# How many pieces of clothing is Spider-Man's costume comprised of in the Sam Raimi film trilogy?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, clothing

How many pieces of clothing is Spider-Man's costume comprised of in the Sam Raimi film trilogy?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not sure I understand the question.  Spider-Man has lots of suits; which one?  And the content of the question makes no sense.  Please write a complete and focused question.

Comment: Peter takes one of his boots off to shake sand out of it in the third film, so it's definitely not a one-piece. Or at least, that version of the costume wasn't. I don't think he wore the exact same suit in the first two films, so I guess one of those could've been a one-piece, but I doubt it. Partly for practical reasons, and partly because his costume wasn't a one-piece in the comics, and I don't see why they'd change that for the films. Sure, they changed other things, but I don't see any benefit to changing that.

Comment: If you want to ask a question, you must write fully formed sentences.

Comment: @Valorum Doesn't Spider-Man normally have gloves that aren't part of his onesie?

Answer (score 5):

Judging by these images from the second and third films, the mask, gloves and boots are all separate pieces, meaning there are at least six parts to the suit in total.

> [image: Image of Spider-Man's costume from "Spider-Man 2" (2004).]
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man 2* (2004)</sub>

> [image: Image of Spider-Man's costume from "Spider-Man 3" (2007).]
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man 3* (2007)</sub>

Mind you, he didn't wear an identical suit in all three films, so there could've been differences between the suits in that regard.